# Unable to db.authenticate() - "Cannot find user"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a local test environment with a mongod on localhost and a db "test" with a user "john". In robomongo, the user "john" is shown in db "test".

In my Node.js program:

- I connect via URI "mongodb://localhost:27017" (no database specified)
- db.db("test") -> ok
- db.authenticate("john", "xxx") -> err.message is "Authentication failed"

Mongod on localhost: "UserNotFound: Could not find user john@test"

How can I create users in the database "test" and authenticate against "test"?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/

Comment: Please provide the output of running "show users" in the test database.

Comment: Are you using the node mongodb driver or orm like mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to authenticate, the user must be in the admin database.

You grant it access to the "test" database by creating a role that has access to it and assign to the user "john".

You can find more details in the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the mongo driver from http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/ (using Bluebird promises and typescript) make sure you have an admin or user with the rights to add users and then:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
    .then(
        (db) => {
            return db.authenticate(
                <admin from above username>,
                <admin from above password>
            )
            .then(
                (success) => {
                    if(success) {
                        return Promise.resolve(db)
                    } else {
                        return Promise.reject('Yikes!');
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
    .then(
        (db) => {
            const options = {
                w: 1,
                roles: ['readWrite']
            }
            return db.addUser(
                <username>,
                <password>,
                options
            )
        }
    );
```

1) Basically connect to the database you need to add the user to as a user with rights to add users (like admin). On a successful retrieval you will have the db object.

2) Decide which roles you want to assign, in this case I have hard coded 'readWrite'.

3) Call db.addUser with the username and password (and options which is the roles). http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Db.html#addUser

Comment: Thanks for all the auswers!

That's intersting. The more I read and learn about MongoDB's authentication, the more I geht confused.

On my local host, I dropped and created a new test database. In this database (and not in "admin") I added ohne which was able to authenticate. This is in contrast to some documentation which teils me to add all users in "admin".

So what is the "right" way? My MongoDB server needs to host several applications, which have their own users.

Comment: I'm working on an app where each client gets their own database so I add the users to each client's respective database as described in my answer. All users however are stored in the admin database so you can search the 'system.users' table and find info about them (like whether they exist).